# Angular Momentum vs Moment of Inertia

Tags: angular-momentum, moment-of-inertia

Pretty sure that this question has already been answered in this site, but I cannot find it. Anyway, here's the question: What is the difference between angular momentum and moment of inertia?

Comment: I won't be surprised if this question is marked as duplicate, but I just need a link to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular momentum is the "moment of momentum", meaning it gives us an idea of how far is the linear momentum vector applied at. Torques involve the moment arm of a force, and angular momentum involves the moment arm of momentum.

## Particle Mechanics

Take a single particle moving in a straight line (in the absence of external forces). It has mass $m_i$, it is located at vector $\boldsymbol{r}_i$ with velocity vector $\boldsymbol{v}_i$. This sets us up for the following definitions

- **Linear Momentum** of particle, $$ \boldsymbol{p}_i = m_i \boldsymbol{v}_i $$
- **Angular Momentum** about the origin, $$ \boldsymbol{L}_i = \boldsymbol{r}_i \times \boldsymbol{p}_i $$

> The above is sufficient to recover the location of the path line, at least the point on the path of the particle closest to the origin.
>
> $$ \boldsymbol{r}_{\rm path} = \frac{ \boldsymbol{p}_i \times \boldsymbol{L}_i }{ \| \boldsymbol{p}_i \|^2} $$
>
> <sub>You can easily prove this if you show that $\boldsymbol{L}_i = \boldsymbol{r}_{\rm path} \times \boldsymbol{p}$, which you do with vector triple product identity $\boldsymbol a\times( \boldsymbol b \times \boldsymbol c) = \boldsymbol b (\boldsymbol a \cdot \boldsymbol c) - \boldsymbol c ( \boldsymbol a \cdot \boldsymbol b)$.</sub>

So in summary, *Angular momentum describes the (permendicular) distance where linear momentum acts*. The conservation of angular momentum law means that not only linear momentum as a vector is conserved, but also the location of this vector (or the line in space the vector acts through) is conserved.

## Rigid Body Mechanics

When you extend the above to multiple particles clumped together as a rigid body the concept of moment of inertia arises. First off, Charles's theorem state that for all the distances to be maintained, each particle can only move with a combination of translation and rotation (with vector $\boldsymbol{\omega}$) about a common axis. Commonly the center of mass is used as a reference point, and so the motion of each particle in the body is restricted to $\boldsymbol{v}_i = \boldsymbol{v}_{\rm com} + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times  \boldsymbol{r}_i$.

Commonly the motion is decomposed to the translation of the center of mass, and the rotation about the center of mass. This yields the following relationships

- **Linear Momentum** of rigid body, $$\boldsymbol{p} = \sum \limits_i m_i \boldsymbol{v}_i = m \boldsymbol{v}_{\rm com}$$
- **Angular Momentum** about center of mass, $$\boldsymbol{L}_{\rm com} = \sum \limits_i \boldsymbol{r}_i \times m_i \boldsymbol{v}_i = \sum \limits_i m_i \boldsymbol{r}_i \times ( \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{r}_i ) $$

### Mass moment of inertia

In order to understand angular momentum of a rigid body rotating about the center of mass better, it is common to separate the geometry parts from the motion parts

$$ \boldsymbol{L}_{\rm com} = \underbrace{ \mathrm{I}_{\rm com} }_{\text{geometry}} \;\;\underbrace{ \boldsymbol{\omega}}_{\text{motion}} $$ where

$$ \mathrm{I}_{\rm com} = \sum_i (-m_i [\boldsymbol{r}_i \times][\boldsymbol{r}_i \times]) = \sum_i m_i \left| \matrix{ y^2+z^2 & - x y & - x z \\ - x y & x^2+z^2 & -y z \\ -x z & -y z & x^2+y^2} \right| $$

This is the mass moment of inertia tensor. It is the rotational equivalent to mass, since $\boldsymbol{p} = m \boldsymbol{v}_{\rm com}$ and $\boldsymbol{L}_{\rm com} = \mathrm{I}_{\rm com} \boldsymbol{\omega}$ have a similar form.

> So, mass moment of inertia describes how far away from the rotation axis is the mass distributed at. It conveys the geometry information of angular momentum. So if a known mass moment of inertia about an axis $I$ is described by $I = m r ^2$, it means the geometry of the problem is similar to that of a mass ring with radius $r$.

<sub>More details [in this similar answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/449938/392).</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much! But can you please explain the mass moment of inertia tensor? I don't really get it.

Comment: A tensor (or matrix) is multiple values combined into one quantity. Mass is a scalar quantity, but the mass moment of inertia is not. Push an object along various directions and you will feel the same mass regardless. Try to rotate a body about various directions and the inertial resistance you feel varies. This is expressed by the 3×3 symmetric inertia tensor $$\mathrm{I} = \left| \matrix{ I_{xx} & I_{xy} & I_{xz} \\ I_{xy} & I_{yy} & I_{yz} \\ I_{xz} & I_{yz} & I_{zz} } \right| $$

Answer (score 2):

Eventhough @ja72 contribuited with his answer analysing the physics of rotational physics, I would like to contribuite a bit in a more mathematical sense between the concept of moment of inertia and the mathematical object called *tensor*.
Actually, the moment of inertial is the *"freshman"* encounter with tensors, because it's appearence is natural in Newtonian Physics.

It's well-known that the relationship between the angular momentum $\vec{L}$ of a particle and the angular velocity $\vec{\omega}$ is then a linear relationship:

$$ \vec{L} = \mathcal{I} \vec{\omega} \tag{1}$$

But this case is a particular case when the rotational  system do not *have* the contribuition of moment of inertia from other directions. Physically speaking this system can rotate only around $z$-axis ($\hat{k}$ direction) or $y$-axis ($\hat{j}$ direction) or $x$-axis ($\hat{i}$ direction) and also rotating around a direction of a vector $\vec{v} = x\hat{i} + y\hat{j} + z\hat{k}$

[image]

But in a arbitrary rotational motion, the contribuition of the moment of inertial of other axis will be appreciable and then the linear relationship $(1)$ have no meaning.

Instead the relationship is performed by another kind of physical quantity called *Inertia Tensor*:

$$ \mathfrak{I} = \sum^{3}_{i=1}\sum^{3}_{i=1} I^{ij} \vec{e}_{i}\otimes\vec{e}_{j} \tag{2}$$

Where components $I^{ij}$, are called *components of inertia tensor*. These components have a matrix representation called *Inertia matrix* or (unfortunately) *Inertia Tensor*:

$$ I^{ij} = \sum^{3}_{i=1}\sum^{3}_{j=1} m[\delta^{ij} \mid\mid \vec{r}\mid\mid^{2} - r^{i}r^{j}] \tag{3}$$

The whole object $(2)$ is the real inertia tensor and tensors (in this case of *rank 2*) are objects which lies on a vector space called *Tensor Product* $V\otimes W$ (please keep this for all your academic life: the best (rapid) answer to the question "what is a tensor?", is "it's a element of tensor product".

Then, when we apply the tensor on angular velocity vectors, we get the vector called angular momentum:

$$ \vec{L} = \mathfrak{I}(\vec{\omega}) \tag{4}$$

$---------------------$

Observation:

In fact there's a minor technical (but crucial point) consideration on $(4)$: to perform a linear transformation like $(4)$, we have to define the object which have tensor components $I^{i}\hspace{0.3mm}_{j}$, i.e., an *mixed tensor*:

$$ \mathfrak{I} = \sum^{3}_{i=1}\sum^{3}_{j=1} I^{i}\hspace{0.3mm}_{j} \vec{e}_{i}\otimes\vec{e}^{j} \tag{5}$$

And then (in component form) we perfom a operation called *contraction*, which result the components of angular momentum vector:

$$L^{i} = \sum^{3}_{j=1}I^{i}\hspace{0.3mm}_{j} \omega^{j} \tag{6}$$

$$ * * * $$

Some references (For Tensors):

$[1]$ Steven Romam's *Advanced Linear Algebra*

$[2]$ Joshi's * Matrices and Tensors in Physics *

$[3]$ McMahon's *Relativity Demystified*

$[4]$ Lang's *Linear Algebra*

Answer (score 1):

The moment of inertia is a measure of how a mass of a rotating body is distributed about the axis of rotation, and its symbol is $I$. The angular momentum is the mass times the cross product of the vectors $r$ and $v$, or the product of the moment of inertia and the angular velocity $\omega$. Its symbol is L.

Comment: Actually, Michael, the moment of inertia is a measure of how difficult it is to produce angular acceleration in a rotating body that is given a specified torque.  Angular momentum is the rotating equivalent of linear momentum.  For linear momentum, $p=mv$.  The rotational equivalent of mass is $I$ and the rotational equivalent of velocity is $\omega$, so angular momentum is given by $L=I\omega$.